# How to send column Items in apex.server.process pageItems parameter?

Tags: ajax, oracle, oracle-apex

In the Oracle APEX 19.1 documentation for JS API, it is mentioned that we can pass column Items in apex.server.process. How do we use that?

Im trying to send column item value to ajax callback function using `apex.server.process`

I tried the below codes

```
apex.server.process("ajax_1", { pageItems: ["ENAME"] }, {
    target: $("#EMP"), dataType: "text", success: function (pData) {
        alert(pData);
    }
});
```

And

```
apex.server.process("ajax_1", { pageItems: ["ENAME"] }, {
    target: "#EMP", dataType: "text", success: function (pData) {
        alert(pData);
    }
});
```

The grid has Static ID: **EMP** and has a column with name : **ENAME** and Static Id : **ENAME**

And in the Ajax Callback Process (PLSQL)

```
BEGIN
    htp.prn('ENAME : ' ||:ENAME);
END;
```

I get the following error

**ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "ENAME" in application "XXXXX"**

Please help.

Comment: Most of the time items on the page will have an item ID like `P1_ENAME`. You need to use that.

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax Callback Process, you need to access the variables with the Syntax `apex_application.g_x01` to `apex_application.g_x10`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_app.htm#AEAPI214 for details and a small example.

Comment: That is not same a passing column items using pageItems and then using those values using bind variable reference. I'm looking for the case which is mentioned in the oracle docs about using column items in pageItems parameter and using relevant target in pOptions object

Comment: It doesn't matter which version of `apex.server.process` you use to send the ajax request. You must use `apex_application.g_x...` to access the variables in your callback.

Comment: I am aware of using apex_application.g_x... . In the documentation for apex.server.procss it is mentioned that we can pass column Items in "pageItems" parameter. My question is how to use that ?

Comment: I am unable to actually try that at the moment, but maybe use your favorite browser networking debugger to see which variables actually get sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am late, but since I had the same question, I wanted to submit the answer.

If your Javascript looks like this:

```
apex.server.process("test_ajax_variable",
        {
            x01: "Test",
            pageItems: "#P13_ITEM"
        },
        {
            dataType: 'text'
        });
```

You can access the variables in an APEX Process like so:

```
DECLARE
    l_test VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    l_test := apex_application.g_x01 || ', ' || :P13_ITEM;
    htp.p(l_test);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here you are sending Page Items not IG columns.

Answer (score 0):

I might be very late at this point, but I believe I understand the solution to your problem. In your JS code you'd first have to define a view and a model. There are multiple ways to do this, I personally went with calling getCurrentView upon the Interactive Grid widget (method *call("getCurrentView")* is short for *widget().interactiveGrid("getCurrentView")*:

```
var view = apex.region("static-id-of-your-IG").call("getCurrentView");
var model = view.model;
```

From there you can perform a numerous amount of methods (listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/model.html#methods-section)) depending on what your actual needs are: do you want to send all of your records to APEX processing, do you want to send only selected ones etc.
Let's say you only have one record and only one specific column value you'd like to pass. You'd assign a new variable following the view and model definition:

```
var name = model.getValue( someRecord, "ENAME" );
```

or as the documentation states, omit the record when the model shape is record itself as it is in your case:

```
var name = model.getValue( "ENAME" );
```

Now that you got the value, in your APEX server process you can pass the **name** variable as an `apex_application.g_x01` parameter:

```
apex.server.process("your-ajax-process-name",
        {
            x01: name,
        },
        {
            dataType: "text"
        }
    )
```

And as mentioned in earlier answers, you would now be able to access the value in your AJAX Callback process like this:

```
DECLARE
    l_test VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    l_test := apex_application.g_x01;
    htp.p(l_test);
END;
```